# Can I ask my company to let me take my online training course during office hours?

Tags: career-development, germany, work-time, training, skills

As a data scientist in Germany, I have to constantly keep myself updated regarding the tech-tools and new concepts in the field. Some of them are easily done by spending a couple of hours reading some documents. However, some other tools demand taking courses, usually online video-based courses.

So, my question is, what can I ask my company if I want to take an online training course in the form of a few-hours block course or a weekly course?

Some courses take only 4-5 hours to complete. For some others, I need to spend 4-5 hours weekly over 2-3 months.

Taking such time-demanding courses during my private time can unbalance my work-life situation. Also, it takes so long to finish a course that way compared to dedicating a focused office time to the course!

I wondered what is the normal culture for such cases in IT and tech-based companies?

Comment: You may want to add a country tag. Some country have regulation making mandatory for a company to train their employees

Comment: @JoeStrazzere No, they didn't. I recognized what I need at the moment based on the demand and changes in the field.

Comment: At least in the United States, professional development is generally recognized as part of the job and can be done as part of the workday.  In some cases companies will even pay for courses in order to make sure their employees have up to date knowledge.  It's clearly a benefit to the company to have employees be up to date in their fields.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By all means ask!  But before you ask, spend some time and think about how this will improve you as an employee now or in the foreseeable future.

Will this training make you more effective in your current role?
Will this training make you a better candidate for a new role at the current company?

There is the direct cost of the training class but there is also the indirect cost of paying you while you do something other than your normal work.  So make a business case for your management as to why this is a good investment of their money.

Be prepared with options.  Perhaps there is no budget for this currently but it could be budgeted for next month/quarter/year and it might be more feasible then.

I don't know that there is any "standard" answer for this situation.  Some companies strongly encourage training.  For example my current company subscribes to Pluralsight and encourages all developers to spend a couple of hours a week learning.  It's part of the culture and I greatly appreciate it.  But my previous company had a strict "no training" policy.  They didn't allow it during working hours and would not pay for it during free time.

So it just depends on the company.

Answer (score 6):

You can always ask them. Some companies would be happy to assist your growth, especially if you can convince them it also benefits them. Others might not be willing to. In the end you won't know until you ask. Just know that if you can't convince them it has an actual benefit for the company, they're less likely to accept.

Comment: One way to help convince the org is by sharing what you've learned. When work pays for my development e.g. training course or conference attendance, I'll circulate notes afterwards summarising what I learned or even give a presentation, focussing on the bits likely to be useful to my co-workers. That way it's very clear that this time/money is for the employer's benefit and not just my own.

Answer (score 2):

You can ask.

Generally, your manager's view will be that if the courses are **must-have** requirements for you to do the job, then he will likely let you take the courses during the office hours. It is up to you to convince him.

However, if the courses are for extra knowledge enhancement, and do not apply directly to your current job, and you still can do your daily tasks well without taking these courses, then he will likely say something like "***Sorry, but No, you can't take the courses during the office hours as your work time has the highest priority. We have deadlines and due dates for projects. BTW, some people take night classes at colleges to improve their knowledge. So, you may think about that option if you want to take those training classes (i.e. taking the online video courses on your own time...)***".

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the company culture and stance about training.

If your company has a strong culture of keeping the employees up to date on their skills or even new skill set to allow promotions/lateral moves then it may just be a matter of asking your manager. In some cases you may not even have to ask anyone since it would be considered part of your job to stay up to date on your skills.

If it is not the case or you don't know the best way to approach this situation is to book a meeting with your manager to discuss about the company guideline about training (maybe there are already materials or courses in place), this situation but also future situation. E.g. If it was acceptable would it be a one time thing, or would it be implicit that you can take other courses, which frequencies, etc.
For this meeting you need to come prepared with a few points:

- What are the difficulties you are encountering
- Why would this course help you resolve the difficulties
- What benefits the team, project or company would earn from you taking the course.
- A schedule of the time you want to take lessons
- How it will impact (or not) your work and collaboration with others. (Will it endanger a milestone, will you be unavailable at a time you otherwise have meetings...)

Now for you question:

> what is the normal culture for such cases in IT and tech-based companies?

Unless you are in a bad place where you are expected to code, draw or anything else for every hour you are being paid for, it often accepted that you can take some time, anytime, as long as your productivity is not heavily impacted and projects are not endangered. Upskilling for day to day task or even to stay relevant with the industry is often considered a part of your job in the IT.

Comment: Depends on the time you take of course and the company culture. Let's be honest, unless you have someone constantly monitoring you nobody knows exactly how much time and effort you put into tasks. For most software developers if you were to took 1 hour a day to do some training instead of "working" it would be transparent. Better pass an hour a day on training than on social media.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can ask. What you get depends on the situation.

Are you immediately more valuable for the company with the training course? They should pay.

Will you get a raise for your added knowledge? They might not want to pay *both* for the course and the raise.

Are there several people with differing amounts of motivation? You might work hard on that course, your colleague might see it as a paid holiday. Giving a raise to the one who actually benefits from the course might be better.